# SQL LOGIC using 3conditions

Tags: sql

```
course_completions CC
        id  coursemodid userid  state   timemodified
        370     23       2         1    1433582890  
        329     24       89        1    1427771915
        333     30       39        1    1428309816
        332     32       39        1    1428303307
        327     33       40        1    1427689703
        328     34       89        1    1427710711
        303     35       41        1    1410258482
        358     36       99        1    1432020067
        365     25       2         1    1433142455
        304     26       69        1    1410717866
        353     37       95        1    1430387005
        416     38       2         1    1438972465
        300     27       70        1    1409824001
        302     29       74        1    1412055704
        297     30       2         1    1409582123
        301     133      41        1    1410255923
        336     133      91        1    1428398435
        364     133      40        1    1433142348
        312     133      85        1    1425863621

        course_modules CM
        id    course    
        23      6   
        24      6   
        25      6    
        26      6    
        27      6    
        28      6    
        29      8    
        30      8    
        31      8    
        32      8    
        33      8   
        34      5   
        35      5    
        36      5   
        37      5   
        38      5    
        39      9    
        40      9    
        41      9    

        course_mod_settings CMS
        id  course  modinstance     
        27    8         30                  
        28    8         31                  
        29    8         32                  
        30    8         33                  
        31    6         23                  
        32    6         24                  
        33    6         25                  
        34    6         26                  
        35    6         27                  
        36    6         28                  
        37    9         39                  
        38    9         40                  
        39    9         41
```

I need the count of each user has Completed modules, Inprocess modules and Notstarted modules for each course, where getting the count of userids from table CC by taking courseia from table CM, get number of modules that an user has completed from each course.

(A course can have morethan one module and a course can have number of users attempted all modules, few modules or not attempted at all).

So, I need number of users - has done number of modules - in a course. (3 logics)

**Completed.Users means** : If number of modules attempted is equal to number of modinstance from table CMS (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 9, no.modinstance = 9. Because 7 is not equal to 9, They are completed.)

**Inprocess.Users means** : Number of modules attempted should be >0, but not equal to [count(modinstance) per course] (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 7 , no.modinstance = 9. Because 7 is not equal to 9, They are Inprocess.)

**Notstarted.Users means** : Number of modules attempted should be equal to 0, (ex: no. of modules attempted by a user per course= 0. They are Notstarted).

```
    OUTPUT :
Course   No.Completed.Users   No.Inprocess.Users    No.Notstarted.Users
 5              65                 32                       6
 6              40                 12                       15
 8              43                 56                       0
 9               0                 7                        9
```

Sir, this is a very critical logic that I was trying, I couldn't get a solution. I hope stackoverflow developers could help me out. I tried with my query :

```
SELECT cm.course AS "Course",

(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT count(cms.id) FROM course_mod_settings cms) = 
(SELECT count(cmc.coursemodid) FROM course_completions cc JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemodid = cm.id WHERE cmc.state=1 )
THEN COUNT(SELECT count(cmc.coursemodid) FROM course_completions cc JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemodid = cm.id WHERE cmc.state=1 ) END) AS "No.Completed.Users",

(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT count(cms.id) FROM course_mod_settings cms) > 0 AND 
(SELECT count(cms.id) FROM course_mod_settings cms) !=
(SELECT count(cmc.coursemodid) FROM course_completions cc JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemodid = cm.id WHERE cmc.state=1 )
THEN COUNT(SELECT count(cmc.coursemodid) FROM course_completions cc JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemodid = cm.id WHERE cmc.state=1 ) END) AS "No.Inprocess.Users",

(CASE WHEN 
(SELECT count(cms.id) FROM course_mod_settings cms) = 0
THEN COUNT(SELECT count(cmc.coursemodid) FROM course_completions cc JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemodid = cm.id WHERE cmc.state=1 ) END) AS "No.Notstarted.Users"

FROM 
mdl_course c 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Is easy for us if you also provide a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23dbf/1)

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the schema relationships.  Also there is serveral typos in your description and is hard to understand what are you describing.

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza - Sir let me know what you don't understand, I would try to express my question.

Comment: To make it simple can we remove `state, time`? also what is `number of modules attempted for user`.  You put an example with 7 and 9 and i dont see that in the data. BTW what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Also dont understand the relationship between tables. What id match what id on what table

Comment: @ronquiq please check SQL fiddle for your schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dea5/1

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza - Yes sir we can remove time

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza - course_completions CC has no. of users and no.modules completed, course_modules CM is only for getting courseid and moduleid, course_mod_settings CMS is for no. modules with target in a coursescore

Comment: Somnath Kadam - There was only one query in the fiddle select * from course_completions

Comment: @ronquiq you have to start with `@` so the user you are talking to get a notification. The idea is you complete the sql fiddle with the whole schema and check if is correct.

Comment: I still dont understand relationship between tables. Calling all field ID doesn't help neither. Tell me how in your output course 9 have (0,7,9) ?

Comment: @ronquiq this is only schema, working on solution.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza - The output i have given is a sample with sample digits. I just want to the output structure like that..

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza - Is there any other way that I could communicate with you by explaining the scenario

Comment: @SomnathKadam What happen with the answer?

Comment: @SomnathKadam - Have you deleted the answer

Comment: @ronquiq That sample data produce that result ouput? If that's the case, please can you explain how you get those values for each course?

Comment: Answer was deleted by StackOverflow, due to very less explanation, I don't know how to undeleted? Link is available here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4be56/4

Comment: @ Somnath Kadam - Could you please add time modified column and No.Notstarted.Users column. I was unable to add these column in your query, it says the two columns were unknown.

Comment: No.Notstarted.Users  = count(cc.coursemodid) != count(cms.id) AND count(cc.coursemodid) < 1

Comment: @ Somnath Kadam - Requesting you to have a look

Comment: You really should never use correlated subqueries, they are performance killers.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f275/36/0)

```
SELECT course AS "Course",
       SUM(CASE WHEN completion_count = module_count THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No.Completed.Users",
       SUM(CASE WHEN completion_count > 0 AND completion_count < module_count THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No.Inprocess.Users",
       SUM(CASE WHEN completion_count = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No.Notstarted.Users"
  FROM (SELECT course, COUNT(*) AS module_count
          FROM course_modules cm 
         GROUP BY course) course_module_counts JOIN
       (SELECT cm.course AS courseid, users.id AS userid, SUM(CASE WHEN cc.state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) completion_count
          FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT userid AS id FROM course_completions) users CROSS JOIN course_modules cm) LEFT JOIN course_completions cc ON users.id = cc.userid AND cc.coursemodid = cm.id
         GROUP BY cm.course, users.id) course_completion_counts
       ON course_module_counts.course = course_completion_counts.courseid
 GROUP BY course
```

gives this output, which matches the limited dataset that you provided in your question.

```
| course | No.Completed.Users | No.Inprocess.Users | No.Notstarted.Users |
|--------|--------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
|      5 |                  0 |                  5 |                   7 |
|      6 |                  0 |                  4 |                   8 |
|      8 |                  0 |                  4 |                   8 |
|      9 |                  0 |                  0 |                  12 |
```